# the loop of sending messages python-telegram-bot-api aiogram

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot, aiogram

I am writing a bot that will give out various media by certain tags. the user writes a request, it is processed and everything found in the database is converted into a list of links of these media, which will then be sent to the user. For example, the script found 100 media satisfying the search query.

how to issue messages in a loop of n messages (for example, n = 10), and to continue issuing, you need to press the inline button? I thought to use AsyncIOScheduler, but as far as I understand, it outputs a cycle over a time interval, but I need exactly the trigger of pressing the button
what do I need to use for this? any scheduler or other handlers?

I was asked to insert a bot initialization block, I don't understand why, if it's standard for any python telegram bot, but okay, here it is

```
#import block
import asyncio
import string
from asyncio.log import logger
import json

from aiogram.bot.api import TelegramAPIServer

from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
import logging
import sqlite3
from aiogram.utils.callback_data import CallbackData
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.bot import bot
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hlink

import config
from utils import States

# Init block
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())
dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())
cb = CallbackData('id', 'action')
```

for example, my unfinished code

```
@dp.message_handler(state=States.S_SEND)
async def senn_media(link_list, message: types.Message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id

    for length in range(10):
        caption1 = ("some text")
        media1 = link_list[array]
        await bot.send_video(chat_id, media1, caption=caption1, parse_mode="HTML")
```

Comment: One point of clarification. I think you mean "loop" instead of "cycle".

Comment: Also, what is `bot`? Where is this variable declared and initialized? You should post a more complete example that includes the initialization code.

Comment: and what should I post about initialization? his token and other config? for what? initializing what? the rest of the bot's code has nothing to do with this issue. there is the implementation and tracking of the start, the search query, checking the subscription to the chat. will it help you in solving my question?

Comment: At the least, you should post the part of the code that declares the variable `bot`.

Comment: it's all standard, I don't understand how it will help, but well, I added.

Comment: Thanks. It helps because it makes your example self-contained. Not everyone that reads this will be familiar with the libraries you are using. Even if they are, you should remove any possibility of incorrect assumptions by posting complete code.